# How is the scroll effect achieved in this webpage?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I want to develop a personal website and i would like it to react/work the same as this website:

http://www.beoplay.com/products/beoplayh6

The scroll not working like usual and rather transitioning between different sections?

I wonder if the sections have a id that are anchored in some way and a css transition is applied when the user scrolls in a direction?

If anyone knows how this is made, please share.

I am looking for the section transition effects essentially.

Thanks in advance

Harry

Comment: It is called  parallax scrolling search for it in google

Comment: Is it parallax, or simple scrolling with some easing?

Comment: I don't think that's parallax at all...

Comment: @Akshay That is not parallax scrolling. That just slides images into the viewport when you reach a ceratin section. Parallax is when you have two or more layers moving at different speeds.

Comment: @Cristy yeah got it Alex Thomas's answer was really helpful

Answer (score 1, accepted):

YOu can create it by using [fullPage.js](http://alvarotrigo.com/fullPage/) with the option `scrollBar:true`.

[Live demo](http://alvarotrigo.com/fullPage/examples/scrollBar.html)

Answer (score 1):

Try this : 
https://ihatetomatoes.net/how-to-create-a-parallax-scrolling-website/

(I'm not related to this site - just think its kinda nifty)

Answer (score 1):

It's not paralax, it's just scrolling with some added easing. Check this for a good start - http://css-tricks.com/examples/SmoothPageScroll/

Comment: Similar, but with the mouse. Most like [fullPage.js](http://alvarotrigo.com/fullPage/)